# How do I program multiple output nodes using the neuralnet package in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am building a neural network to predict "fit" based on a number of variables. "FitCls" is in three classes: "Excellent", "Good" and "Poor". I have 10 input variables, and have chosen one hidden layer with 6 neurons. I would like three output neurons so that I can classify the case that is presented to the neural network as a "fit" which is "excellent", "good" or "poor". 
I have seen a similar example where this was done using iris data (on slide 40, et seq.) here: http://www.slideshare.net/DerekKane/data-science-part-viii-artifical-neural-network. I have tried to copy that structure, but I still only get a single output node when I plot the network.

Here is my code (after loading the 'nfit' dataframe):

```
nfit[nfit$FitCls=="Excellent", "Output"] <- 2  
nfit[nfit$FitCls=="Good", "Output"] <- 1
nfit[nfit$FitCls=="Poor", "Output"] <- 0
nn <- neuralnet(Output~Universalism+Benevolence+Tradition+Conformity+Security+Power+Achievement+Hedonism+Stimulation+SelfDir, data = nfit, hidden = 6, err.fct = "ce", linear.output = FALSE)
```

When I run neuralnet, it gives me a warning message that it has forced err.fct to "sse" because the response is not binary.  I am not sure what is going wrong because in the example that I am copying, the plot of the neural network shows three output nodes. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

If this is not the right way to go about using neuralnet for classification I would also appreciate any help you can provide as to what I should be doing. Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe the library is treating your response variable as a number. Have you tried making the `FitCls` column into a factor column? `nfit$FitCls <- as.factor(nfit$FitCls)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried that, but neuralnet doesn't seem to be able to handle factors in that way. That approach works with nnet, but for some reason, not with neuralnet.

Answer (score 4):

To more or less replicate the iris example you will need:

```
library(neuralnet)
library(nnet)
trainset <- cbind(iris[, 1:4], class.ind(iris$Species))
espnnet2=neuralnet(setosa + versicolor + virginica ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, trainset)
plot(espnnet2)
```

[image]

Unfortunately neuralnet is sensible to data, try `scale` the explanatory variables.